# Which file should I use Accounts.sendVerificationEmail?

Tags: meteor, user-accounts

I implemented login functionality using Meteor. I want to send a verification email whenever a new user is created. According to the documentation, I should use:

Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userId, [email])

on the server folder.

However, I feel that it is lacking in implementation details. What file should I create to use this method? Does it have to be in a specific folder?

Answer (score 0):

I made file in `../server/config.coffee`:

```
Accounts.config
  sendVerificationEmail: true
  forbidClientAccountCreation: false

Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName = "blabla.com"
Accounts.emailTemplates.from = "blabla.com site Admin <admin@blabla.com>"

Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.subject = (user) ->
  "Confirm registration on " + Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName;

Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.text = (user, url) ->
   "To confirm your registration, please, click this link " + url
```

Of course, you have to setup `process.env.MAIL_URL` too.

Comment: Hi! Where should I setup process.env.MAIL_URL?

Comment: I've set up in the same file `process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://user@gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:465/"`